# Using a dictionary within a class from user input in python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

Here's my current code:

```
class city1:
    dict = {"north":"city2", "east": 0, "south": 0, "west": "city3"}

validcmds = ['north', 'east', 'south', 'west']
input=raw_input(">>")
input=set(input.split())
validcmds=set(validcmds)
output = list(validcmds.intersection(input))
print city1.dict(output)
```

I don't know what's wrong with this line:

```
print city1.dict(output)
```

Basically I just want the output to be looked up in the dict in the city1 class. It's for my texted based RPG :)

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use the word `dict`.  You mask the built-in `dict()` method when you do so.  Next, you can use the `d.get(key)` method to retrieve elements from a dictionary.

You may want to review your code, as I'm not convinced that it works in its current state, even after you retrieve elements from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use parentheses to access a dictionary. Use `print city1.dict[output]` instead. However, it looks like you're making a list out of dictionary keys, and Python will complain that this isn't hashable if you try to index on a list like that.

If `output` has multiple keys in it, then try this instead:

```
print [city1.dict[elem] for elem in output]
```

It's also bad practice to name a data structure after its type. I would consider re-naming `dict` as something else, such as `city_dict` or something more descriptive.

Comment: Thank you :) I assumed as it was part of the city1 class that calling it dict would be ok :) just looked through my code and realised I was being very stupid :) thank you :) I often get into a muddle then work it out myself, I should really have seen this one!!

Answer (score 0):

output is a list of keys. You can't key your dict with a list of keys at once. You should do:
`print [city1.dict[x] for x in output]`

By the way, `input` is a method, and by assigning to input you deleted that command.. (not that it matters here, but you might like to know)